# How to determine with JGit which branches have been merged to master?

Tags: jgit

How do I use JGit to determine which branches have been merged to master?

I want to do the equivalent of the normal git command:

```
git branch -a --merged
```

Is this possible in JGit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RevWalk::isMergedInto()` can be used to determine if a commit was merged into another. That is, `isMergedInto` returns true if the commit given in the first argument is an ancestor of the second given commit.

```java
try (RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(repository)) {
  RevCommit masterHead = revWalk.parseCommit(repository.resolve("refs/heads/master");
  RevCommit otherHead = revWalk.parseCommit( repository.resolve("refs/heads/other-branch");
  if (revWalk.isMergedInto(otherHead, masterHead)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

To get a list of all branches the `ListBranchesCommand` is used:

```java
List<Ref> branches = Git.wrap(repository).listBranches().setListMode(ListMode.ALL).call();
```

Comment: Yes, with the `LsRemoteCommand` you can retrieve all refs that are available on the remote repository.

Comment: But how do I get the repository from the LsRemoteCommand? .getRepository return null

Comment: Your comment seems not related to this question. If you have a question regarding the `LsRemoteCommand`, please ask with a separate post.